# What is the meaning of "Wake up sneezing"?

Tags: phrases

I am confused about one thing about that phrase "wake up sneezing". Does it mean that I wake up because of sneezing, or I wake up then I sneeze?

Comment: Context please.  I assume you read this somewhere.  Please tell us where and provide the context.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. It means that when you wake up, you are sneezing.